# Why am I getting the error "missing terminating ] for character class"?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regex

I want to cut a string with brackets using `sed`.

How to avoid an error if I want to drop a string with `[`?
For example:

```
$ echo '[Om/mystring' | grep -oP '(?<=[Om\\)\w+'
grep: missing terminating ] for character class
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error *missing terminating ] for character class* already says, the problem here has to do with `[`, which you need to escape. Otherwise, it is understood as a character class by grep.

Also, you are saying `//`, while you want to use `/` instead of `\` according to your input.

All together, this prints a set of words after `[Om/`:

```
$ echo '[Om/mystring' | grep -oP '(?<=\[Om\/)\w+'
mystring
```

Answer (score 6):

You are getting the error because `[` is a special character in regular expression syntax, introducing a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). To be treated as a string literal, it must be escaped i.e. `\[`

If you just want to *remove* the `[Om/` prefix, then it's simpler sed if you use a delimiter that doesn't appear in the pattern:

```
$ echo '[Om/mystring' | sed 's;\[Om/;;'
mystring
```

Comment: You can also add the anchor `^` to make it match just the beginning of the line.